# How do you detect if the alias is being used in Vue Router's beforeEnter?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

In vue-router's routes.js, if I have a path that has an alias

```
path: "/",
alias: "/secret"
```

Within my `beforeEnter` method, how can I tell if the alias is being accessed?

For example:

```
if (alias === '/secret') {
  console.log('The secret alias was used')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`beforeEnter` receives `to`, `from`, and `next` arguments.

`to` is a Route object, so you can check `to.path`.